# Sonar with Groovy project always reports technical debt of 0.0 days

Tags: groovy, sonarqube

I'm running Sonar 4.0 and the 0.6 Groovy plugin (latest version).  I analyze the project with Sonar Runner 2.3, and the Sonar report gets generated.  When I view the report in the Sonar web server, everything looks great, but the technical debt is always reported as 0.0 days, even though there are 2405 issues (including 2 critical and 587 minor).  Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQALE model (from which the technical debt is computed) is not yet included in the Groovy plugin. Feel free to follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1836