# Sonar 5.1.1 with Groovy Plugin 1.1.1 project always reports technical debt of 0.0 days

Tags: grails, groovy, sonarqube

Upfront: I know there is already the same question on SO, but refereing to different version. ([Sonar with Groovy project always reports technical debt of 0.0 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914171/sonar-with-groovy-project-always-reports-technical-debt-of-0-0-days))

I am trying to get SonarCube 5.1.1 up and running together with the groovy 1.1.1 plugin. Unfortunately, I always the technical debt of 0.0 days.

The Sqale information is included in the groovy plugin, so it seems that this isn't the problem.

Any other idea?

Comment: Same issue for me.  Groovy issues get flagged but not included in technical debt ratio.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Sonar-Groovy plugin introduced with this [commit](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-groovy/commit/633551f64397ee95c0d7478cd961a22ecdff9052) 
Migrating the API to rules definition and using the latest version of SonarQube lead to ignore the sqale mapping alltogether.

A ticket has been created to fix the issue : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGROOV-35

Comment: Great! If you manage to fix this before the bounty ends, you'll get the full bounty as reward ;-)

Comment: @rdmueller given what I am working on right now, this won't happen ;)

Comment: with the help of your bug description, I managed to compile a version which works! I raised a pull request - maybe it helps.